# Check if user input is in range and append value to result

Tags: c#, typescript

So I want to do some validation on user input. If the user enters a number from 1-10, I want to append a `0` preceding it. E.g if a user enters `4` I want to store in a variable the value `04`. I know how to do this in C# but struggling to achieve it in TypeScript. I have attached the C# code that does this exact thing. I want to be able to do it in a component class for my Angular 5 application.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<int> collection = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        collection.Add(i);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your input below: " + "\n");
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine();
    if (collection.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(input)))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("True" + "\n");
        var result = "0" + input;
        Console.WriteLine("Appended Result: " + result);
    }
    else 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("False");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

I am using `Typescript version 2.3.3.0`

Comment: check your input with `isNaN(num1)` then apply your logic, `isNaN(num1)` will return true if your string is number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Direct port of your C# results in the following code:

```js
var collection = [...Array(10).keys()];

var num = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number"));

if(collection.indexOf(num) !== -1) {
  console.log("0" + num);
} else {
  console.log(num);
}
```

> TypeScript Rocks! So even shorter code would be:

```js
num = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number"));

num = num < 10 ? "0" + num : num;

console.log(num);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following to achieve this

```
paddedNumber(num:number, size:number): string {
    let s = num+"";
    while (s.length < size) s = "0" + s;
    return s;
}
```